# How to Multithreading Python with my laptop

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have project in python, structure of my project like this :

```
def makeRecommendation:    
         .....do something here....
         insertRecomenderToDB(result)

def insertRecomenderToDB(result):
          .....do something here....

if __name__ == '__main__':
   makeRecommendation()
```

**My laptop " Core i7 with number of cores : 4, processors(logical processors) : 8**

Everytime i run my project, its run only one processor. I want make all 8 processors running, i read about Multithreading but not really understand how to make all 8 processors run in my laptop.

How i can make 8 processors with my project ?

Thanks very much for help me !

Comment: What would running your project on 8 processors help you accomplish? I don't see any multi-threading in your project that would be aided by additional processors.

Comment: Multiprocessing for using multiple cores. Multi-threading uses a single core only

Comment: I think about `import multiprocessing` or `import threading` but don't know how to write it in my poroject.

Answer (score 0):

Python's multithreading cannot make use of multicore. The only way is to use multi-processing. There are several modules that you could use:

[multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html): This module gives you complete control over new process.
[concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html): This is more convenient, it allows you to create a process pool quickly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @laike9m . Can you give me example if i want use multicore with values in dictionary. I mean if i have dictionary with 10  pairs key:value, and i set 5 cores then program run 5 pairs key:value in one time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean……You can always pass arguments to new process no matter which one you use.